# Method with a dynamic number of type parameter

Tags: scala

I would merge this two methods :

```
def get[A](m: Map[String, Any], k: String) = 
  m(k).asInstanceOf[A]

def get[A, B](m: Map[String, Any], k1: String, k2: String) = 
  (m(k1).asInstanceOf[A], m(k2).asInstanceOf[B])
```

For parameters, I can use varargs.
Is there a solution for types ?

[update] This example is lightweight to focus on the point.
In my real use case, Map is an object returns by my DB driver (a MongoDBObject returns by Casbah).

[update2] Here is the real code

```
def getH0(query: Query, magic: Boolean = false): Iterable[Long] =
  getHits(query, magic)((o: DBObject) => o.as[Long]("hits"))

def getH1[A](query: Query, magic: Boolean = false): Iterable[(A, Long)] =
  getHits(query, magic)(asTuple[A, Long]("_id", "hits"))

def getH2[A, B](query: Query, magic: Boolean = false): Iterable[((A, B), Long)] =
  getHits(query, magic)(asTuple3[A, B, Long](query.dimension.get.apply(0), query.dimension.get.apply(1), "hits"))

def getHits[T](query: Query, magic: Boolean = false)(f: DBObject => T): Iterable[T] = {
```

Comment: the first get returns an `A`, the second get returns a tuple - `(A, B)`. What result type do you expect the merged method to be?

Comment: @GovindSingh It's not at all a dupe - Yann wants to know what, if anything, can be used to express an arbitrarily long sequence of types, to define the contents of the tuple - to replace `[A, B]`.

Comment: @serejja I'd guess Yann wants a Product[A,B,C,D,...] (invalid syntax to express wish).

Answer (score 0):

You can use varargs if you change the return type to List or something else.

```
def get[A](m: Map[String, Any], k: String*):List[A]=
    k.map(x=>m(x).asInstanceOf[A]).toList //the default return type is Seq
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you need the shapeless library :)

The relevant parts are:

The `Record` type, which is a bit like a `Map` in which the types of all the values are retained.

`HList`, which can be thought of as either a `List` in which element types are retined, or as an arbitrary-length `Tuple`.

Your example is a bit lightweight, which makes it difficult to suggest the best approach for you.